# Class 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed' not found [magento]

Tags: magento

i am trying to display most viewed products on homepage. getting following error.

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract {
    public
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId = Mage::app() - > getStore() - > getId();
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection') - > addOrderedQty() - > addAttributeToSelect('*') - > addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image')) - > setStoreId($storeId) - > addStoreFilter($storeId) - > addViewsCount();
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status') - > addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility') - > addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
        $products - > setPageSize(5) - > setCurPage(1);
        $this - > setProductCollection($products);
    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ifasonx\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 491

refference:- 
http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-show-most-viewed-best-selling-products-in-magento-store/

Answer (score 0):

Because your class name is wrong. Magento Doesn't have class by name Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed .Also please don't Mage namespace under local directory its wrong. Please develop a module for this then prepare a block Namespace_Modulename_Block_Mostviewed then call the function inside it .
Please follow below process .

http://arabgento.com/en/magento-display-best-selling-products-most-viewed-products-new-products-absolutely-or-by-categories/

Then call the block from either phtml or cms